# Converting a string to double in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have built a dataframe using `concat` which produces a string.

```scala
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0))).toDF("k", "v")
df.registerTempTable("df")

val dfConcat = df.select(concat($"k", lit(","), $"v").as("test"))

dfConcat: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test: string]

+-------------+
|         test|
+-------------+
|      1.0,2.0|
|      3.0,4.0|
+-------------+
```

How can I convert it back to double?

I have tried casting to `DoubleType` but I get `null`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
 intterim.features.cast(IntegerType))

val testDouble = dfConcat.select( dfConcat("test").cast(DoubleType).as("test"))

+----+
|test|
+----+
|null|
|null|
+----+
```

and `udf` return number format exception at run time

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val toDbl    = udf[Double, String]( _.toDouble)

val testDouble = dfConcat
.withColumn("test",      toDbl(dfConcat("test")))              
.select("test")
```

Comment: what do you expect to get back ?

Comment: a vector or an array of double for each row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot convert it to double because it is simply not a valid double representation. If you want an array just use `array` function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array

df.select(array($"k", $"v").as("test"))
```

You can also try to split and convert but it is far from optimal:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split

dfConcat.select(split($"test", ",").cast(ArrayType(DoubleType)))
```

Comment: split works fine tks do you mean that it is not optimal because if there is a null or an na it will throw an error?

Comment: No, because why convert something to string and pay the price of parsing if you need numeric in the first place? Moreover arrays are not very useful and don't compress that well.